# How to send argument to error function of ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

I have one question. How to send argument to error function of ajax? Is it possible?

Right now I tried yo use next code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: btn.attr("data-url"),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, data) {
        if(xhr.status==403) {
            location.href = '/documents/'+data.current_category+'/';
        }
    },
});
```

In browser console I see next error:

```
TypeError: data is undefined
```

That data attribute I create in `views.py` file of my Django project:

```
class DocumentCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = ('documents.add_document',)
    raise_exception = True

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = dict()
        # Some other code
        data['current_category'] = self.kwargs.get('category')
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: `xhr.responseText`?

Comment: The data should be in success handler not in error handler

Comment: @SumeshTG Well, let me try to explain the situation. When status code is 403, only in this case I want to redirect user to other url. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: this error won't send any data. user custom error codes handle it in success handler

Answer (score 0):

Firstly on your return in py do :

```
data['status'] = 'success'
```

or

```
data['status'] = 'error'
```

And in your ajax do :

```
$.ajax({
url: btn.attr("data-url"),
type: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
done: function (data) {
    if(data.status === 'error') {
        location.href = '/documents/'+data.current_category+'/';
    }
    else if(data.satus === 'success') { // Do done... }
},
```

});

Comment: Well, let me try to explain the situation. When status code is 403, only in this case I want to redirect user to other url. What additional code I need to add in this case?

Comment: Add the appropriate response where needed. Something like: `response = JsonResponse({'status':'false','message':message}, status=403)`